# Implement slots machine game animation

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I am developing slots machine game in cocos2D. I want to implement the animation of the liver pulling. As in the image attached i want, that the user touches the liver and pull it downwards and the liver gives animation effect like it is being pulled in the way that it is coming outwards in the z direction to the half way downwards. How can i achieve this animation effect?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make the lever a 3d model in blender(free) skin the model with the lever.

In blender animate the lever and then save the animation images frame by frame.

Make a list of png files for each frame(objective c does not like gif files)

Make an animation array and a UIImageView. Set that UIImageViews animationimages to the array.

When you want the user to simulate pulling the lever set the UIImageView to animating with a repeat count of 1.

Copy the animation backwards to have it go back into place if you want to.

Comment: Hi @Necro - It their any other approach to do this.. Something like I am able to make the bottom point of the liver fixed and move the liver.. ??

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - Can you help me on this?

Comment: Did you make the texture for the lever yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer has been given, if you want the game to have a 3d looking lever.

Another approach is to increase the size of the lever ball (SPIN) as you shrink the height of the handle.  This would also give a similar look to the handle moving towards and away from the player.